# AWS - Education account cannot create cluster, insufficient EC2 permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

My education AWS account cannot create a cluster. It gives me such error

> Core - 2: Service role EMR_DefaultRole has insufficient EC2 permissions.

I have searched the AWS support centre and the web, and barely can any solution.
I've tried to contact the AWS expert team, but somehow I cannot contact them.

This error is encountered when I try to create a PySpark EMR with 4 r5.xlarge cores. If the number of the cores reduces to 2, and the type change to m5.2xlarge, the cluster can be created without error.

The account type is AWS Educate Starter Account.

Any suggestion will be appreciated. :)

Comment: You mean AWS Educate starter account?

Comment: What exactly was you doing when you saw this error?

Comment: looks like EC2 roles have to be created as per their documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles.html

Comment: The details and context are updated. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The AWS Educate Starter Account is very [limited](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf).

It only allows the following instances:

> "t2.small","t2.micro","t2.nano","m4.large","c4.large","c5.large","m5.large","t2.medium","m4.xlarge","t2.nano","c4.xlarge","c5.xlarge","t2.2xlarge","**m5.2xlarge**","t2.large","t2.xlarge","m5.xlarge"

As you can see, instance **`r5.xlarge` is not permitted**. However, `m5.2xlarge` is allowed, thus it works for you.