# AWS EMR - EMR_DefaultRole has insufficient EC2 permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

I'm trying to create a new EMR cluster (tried emr-5.30.0 and emr-6.0.0 versions) but I'm receiving the validation message error: "Terminated with errorsService role EMR_DefaultRole has insufficient EC2 permissions".

I've tried this workaround https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-default-role-invalid/  recreating the default roles for EMR but the validation message error still happening.

Any guidance or recommendations on how to resolve this issue are much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Are you using an AWS Educate Starter Account ? If yes, I had this error as well. I found a similar question here on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790487/aws-education-account-cannot-create-cluster-insufficient-ec2-permission) that could help you

Answer (score 5):

Based on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=947039

for me it was very helpful troubleshooting via AWS CloudTrail:

1. Navigate to the Cloudtrail console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/
2. Click on **Event History** tab
3. Then use filter as **Event Source** and in Time range select the timestamp during cluster launch.
4. From the buttons on Right side, click on the Gear Icon, which is for Show/Hide columns and select the **Error Code** column check box.

Once all the above is done, go through the list of events and expand the one which has an ErrorCode like *AccessDenied*, *Client.UnauthorizedOperation* or any other exception.

Once you know which API call is being denied, you can then investigate further regarding the same.

Comment: 4th point is killer feature)

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on from @Vzzarr's method you might be able to retrieve more error information.

1. Navigate to the Cloudtrail console: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/
2. Click on **Event History** tab
3. Click on the event with the error in the list.
4. Look for an `errorMessage` key.

If the value contains something like *Encoded authorization failure message:* with a random string following it. You can decode that message with the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) using [decode-authorization-message from STS](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/decode-authorization-message.html)

```
aws sts decode-authorization-message --encoded-message "<paste encoded message here>"
```

You should get a json string back like

```
{ "DecodedMessage": "....}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This pointed us in the right direction. We needed to add the SCP policy so that I could provision those instance types with my account.

Answer (score 1):

Took a lot of time to fix it but finally fixed it.

The error log "EMR_DefaultRole has insufficient EC2 permissions" is 50% correct I can say and it is not reflecting the exact error.

If you are facing the same error then you must have using AWS multi account architecture and there must been some SCP applied over your account.

Check with your organisation admin or if you have access check SCP as a first step.

In my case some tagging was enforced for EC2 and while I was creating EMR with EC2 node, I was not passing the tag and my SCP failing my EMR cluster creation.

Later on , I passed all the tags in EMR, which eventually pass the same tag to EC2 and finally it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! This pointed us in the right direction. We needed to add the SCP policy so that I could provision those instance types with my account.